# Class component to functional component is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am implementing infinite scrolling with react-native, when I do a search the result is returned and if the result has many pages on the API, when I scroll the API returns more data .

my implementation works fine on the class component but when I try to convert it to a working component, when I do a search, the data is returned and if I did another search, the previous data from the previous search is still displayed

class component

```
class Exemple extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.searchedText = "";
    this.page = 0;
    this.totalPages = 0;
    this.state = {
      films: [],
      isLoading: false,
    };
  }

  _loadFilms() {
    if (this.searchedText.length > 0) {
      this.setState({ isLoading: true });
      getFilmsWithSearch(this.searchedText, this.page + 1).then((data) => {
        this.page = data.page;
        this.totalPages = data.total_pages;
        this.setState({
          films: [...this.state.films, ...data.results],
          isLoading: false,
        });
      });
    }
  }
  
  _searchTextInputChanged(text) {
    this.searchedText = text;
  }

  _searchFilms() {
    this.page = 0;
    this.totalPages = 0;
    this.setState(
      {
        films: [],
      },
      () => {
        this._loadFilms();
      }
    );
  }

  _displayLoading() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.loading_container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textinput}
          placeholder="Titre du film"
          onChangeText={(text) => this._searchTextInputChanged(text)}
          onSubmitEditing={() => this._searchFilms()}
        />
        <Button title="Rechercher" onPress={() => this._searchFilms()} />
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.films}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <FilmItem film={item} />}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
          onEndReached={() => {
            if (this.page < this.totalPages) {
              this._loadFilms();
            }
          }}
        />
        {this._displayLoading()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

the functional component

```
const Search = () => {
  const [films, setFilms] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(0);
  const [searchedText, setSearchedText] = useState("");

  const _loadFilms = () => {
    if (searchedText.length > 0) {
      setIsLoading(true);
      getFilmsWithSearch(searchedText, page + 1).then((data) => {
        setPage(data.page);
        setTotalPages(data.total_pages);
        setFilms([...films, ...data.results]);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    _loadFilms();
  }, []);

  const _searchTextInputChanged = (text) => {
    setSearchedText(text);
  };

  const _searchFilms = () => {
    setPage(0);
    setTotalPages(0);
    setFilms([]);
    _loadFilms();
  };

  const _displayLoading = () => {
    if (isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.loading_container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        </View>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.main_container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.textinput}
        placeholder="Titre du film"
        onChangeText={(text) => _searchTextInputChanged(text)}
        onSubmitEditing={() => _searchFilms()}
      />
      <Button title="Rechercher" onPress={() => _searchFilms()} />
      <FlatList
        data={films}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <FilmItem film={item} />}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        onEndReached={() => {
          if (page < totalPages) {
            _loadFilms();
          }
        }}
      />
      {_displayLoading()}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Just a guess, maybe you've looked at this already; but maybe look at how you are using the `useEffect` as this is running every time the component state is updating and you're calling loadfilms which keeps the exsisting films and adds new ones. Check the state of the films after you call `setFilms([])` in the `_searchFilms` function to check the films array is empty.

Comment: @JakeB. i have checked it's working but i must click 2 times on the button, like this     if (films.length === 0) {
      _loadFilms();
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With functional components, you cannot run effects (like `getFilmsWithSearch`) outside of `useEffect`.

From https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

> Mutations, subscriptions, timers, logging, and other side effects are not allowed inside the main body of a function component (referred to as React’s render phase). Doing so will lead to confusing bugs and inconsistencies in the UI.

When you are calling `_loadFilms` from within then `onSubmitEditing={() => _searchFilms()}` event handler, you are not running inside `useEffect`, unlike the call to `_loadFilms` from `useEffect` that runs with the component mounts (because the second parameter to `useEffect` is `[]`, it runs once on mount).

To solve this issue, you would typically have `_searchFilms` set a state variable (something like `reloadRequested`, but it does not have to be a boolean, see the article below for a different flavor) and have a second `useEffect` something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (reloadRequested) {
      _loadFilms();
      setReloadRequested(false);
    }
  }
, [reloadRequested])
```

For a more complete example with lots of explanation, try this article https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data.